# Change trains in Brest (Belarus) under 15 minutes?

Tags: transit, trains, train-stations, belarus

My mother is arriving at the [Brest-Tsentralny railway station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brest-Tsentralny_railway_station) at 10:28 from Moscow (train number 007M).

Unfortunately, she only has 15 minutes to catch the train to Paris at 10:43 (train number 023Й).

I found a plan of the station:

[image: Brest-Tsentralny railway station]

And it looks like she'd need to cross the bridge from the bottom half (Moscow-side) to the upper half (Warsaw-side).

I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to know in advance from which of the platforms the train to Warsaw (at 10:43) will be departing?
2. Is the bridge operational? (Asking because I stumbled upon [this article](https://brestcity.com/blog/zakryt-vyxod-s-peshexodnogo-mosta-na-2-i-3-puti-moskovskoj-storony-zhd-vokzala-v-breste) from 2018 where is says that some platforms were unreachable from the bridge).

Thank you!

Comment: Not a full answer, but if she’s lucky enough to arrive and depart from the platforms closest to the building it’s just a walk-across afair.

Comment: The train from Brest to Paris starts in Moscow.  Why isn't she picking up the train in Moscow already?

Comment: @gerrit: Unfortunately, she narrowly missed the train. Damn traffic jams in Moscow.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to know in advance from which of the platforms the train to Warsaw (at 10:43) will be departing?

No, even on train tracking websites I was unable to get this information. There are only 4 platforms it could depart from.

> Is the bridge operational? (Asking because I stumbled upon this article from 2018 where is says that some platforms were unreachable from the bridge).

To clarify, the bridge was non-operational to enter the Moscow track platform 2 and 3. The article states it is unknown when the works will finish. The work will have most likely finished. If not, the work is only 400 metres longer and you should follow the advice of that website.

The train will wait at the station for 2 hours and 33 minutes. You should be fine.

Comment: Conserning your last paragraph: please note that the train Moscow--Paris does indeed spend 2 h and 33 min in Brest, but it's from 08:10 till 10:43. So she has only 15 minutes.

Comment: @Leo ok, but it’s still more than enough time

Comment: Those 2½ hours are for the [Bogie exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogie_exchange) and passport controls.  You cannot assume the train is accessible for passengers during all this time, but it should be just prior to departure.